# how to convert date in text field to UK date format of dd/mm/yyyy in ms access?

Tags: asp.net, date, ms-access-2007

I want to display all dates greater than equal to today's date but the dates are stored in a text field.How to convert it into date format ? 
I tried :

```
    select columns from table where date >= format (DateTime.Today,"dd/mm/yyyy");
```

it returns the dates followed by all other dates in the table .

Also tried :

```
    DateSerial(CInt(Left(jobdate,2)),CInt(Mid(jobdate,3,2)),CInt(Right(jobdate,4))) which gives error.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must convert your text date to true for any comparison to work.

So (in Access):

```
Select columns From table Where DateSerial(Mid(jobdate, 7, 4), Mid(jobdate, 4, 2), Mid(jobdate, 1, 2) >= Date()
```

Comment: Always save and handle dates as date values, not text. That will free you from trouble like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select jobdate,press,jobno,party,qty,jobtype from FNLJOB where Format( jobdate , \"dd/mm/yyyy\") >= Format(Date(),\"dd/mm/yyyy\") ", con);
```

Comment: It still gives me all the dates in the databse

Comment: The date in the db is in a text field. There's some conversion issue.not able to resolve it.

Comment: In  asp.net it gives syntax error with a wiggled underline

Comment: OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select jobdate,press,jobno,party,qty,jobtype from FNLJOB where Format( jobdate , "dd/mm/yyyy") >= Date() ", con);

Comment: I did..no errors this time but still its giving all the dates. thank you for your patience tohgh.